# Ignore stdout in a Scala Process

Tags: shell, scala

I'm porting some old code from Java to Scala that executes a shell command. The Scala code uses the '!!' method from scala.sys.process. The problem that I'm having is that the Scala code is passing the stdout of the shell command through to the stdout of the scala, where I really only want the program to print what I tell it to with println(). Given the following code

```
import scala.sys.process._

class FidoWrapper(file: java.io.File){
  val fido = ("fido " + file.getAbsolutePath).!!
}

object Wrapper{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val wrapper = new FidoWrapper(new java.io.File("src/main/resources/testfile.txt"))
    println("===")
    println("result: " + wrapper.fido.split(",")(0))
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
FIDO v1.3.1 (formats-v70.xml, container-signature-20130501.xml, format_extensions.xml)
FIDO: Processed      1 files in 468.12 msec,  2 files/sec
===
result: OK
```

Where what I would like to have is:

```
===
result: OK
```

This is what my original Java code did. Is there anyway I can redirect the stdout from the shell process so that it doesn't output? Is there any way I can silence the Process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder

with `!` you can specify a `ProcessLogger` to handle all IO.